# SQL: Check size of Data in Insert Operation before Inserting

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

This sounds like a trivial problem and it probably is, but I couldn't find any straightforward answer anywhere.

Basically, I have a SQL stored procedure accepting some parameters. The parameters will be processed to generate values which will be used in an insert operation later on in the stored procedure.

Now, depending on *exceptional* cases, the passed values may result in some insert operations to contain values exceeding max length for a column. I would like to catch those scenarios and not go through the insert operation if it's certain to fail.

Additionally, if such a scenario does occur, I want the stored procedure to terminate in a manner so the calling module knows it didn't succeed, analogical to THROW as used in exception handling in many languages.

Update: I know I can use Try/Catch but it will log error in the *insights* and I want to prevent this.

Comment: Why can't you use `try/catch/throw` ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, actually try catch, although doesn't fail the flow, still logs an error in the insights. I want to avoid this logging.

Comment: You haven't shown any code so I'm not sure what else you're expecting. you'll have to validate your insert in some way. Maybe you can use `where datalength(value) < n` - impossible to say though with no code.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to use a try catch block in your sproc for error handling.

```
BEGIN TRY

    PRINT 'Put Script in this block'

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    THROW

END CATCH
```

Then to be able to tell whether or not a value will exceed the data type length  you will need to get the maximum data length of your column. You can get this using below (if you have permission)

```
SELECT column_name as 'Column Name', data_type as 'Data Type',
character_maximum_length as 'Max Length'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

Lastly you will just need to get the length of your variable. You can do that like below

```
SELECT LEN(@VariableName)
```

Then you just need to put it together